# Do any programming languages define <= before <?

Tags: programming-languages, inequality, equality-operator

Often `a <= b` is defined as `a < b || a == b`. Do any languages make `<=` the more "base" operator and define `a < b` in terms of `<=`, e.g. as `a <= b && !(a == b)`?

Comment: The only example that comes to mind is in Python, you can use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to overload all of the comparison operations on a user-defined class by providing an implementation for any one of `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=`. But if your question is just about language specifications, I'm not sure why it would matter; whichever definition appears in the specification, the two should be equivalent (except for possible edge-cases involving floating-point NaN, but those are usually specified explicitly anyway).

Comment: To clear up a possible misconception, just because the language specification *defines* one operator in terms of the other, doesn't mean that the compiler or interpreter *implements* one in terms of the other.